# k2 module subtemplate doesn't pick up changes after editing - joomla 3.8.0

Tags: php, templates, joomla, joomla3.5

I hope some of you joomla enthusiast can help a beginner with a problem.

So I created a subtemplate for a k2 module in the folder templates/my_template/html/mod_k2_content. This folder contains the two subfolders Default (contains the default.php) and Team (contains the team.php).
The team.php file is the default.php file with minor changes. Everything worked fine and i could select the "Team" subtemplates in the joomla backend and it also showed the changes.  Now I tried to edit the team.php in templates/my_template/html/mod_k2_content/Team again and it just doesn't pick up the changes anymore. When I edit the default.php in templates/my_template/html/mod_k2_content/Default it works just fine on the modules that work with the default subtemplate.

But the modules that have the Team subtemplate selected just stay the same, the way they were when i first selected this subtemplate for the modules.

Anybody that already enountered that problem and knows what I'm doing wrong?
I already reselected the team subtemplate several times and made sure I'm connected to the server. I also encluded a bunch of characters in the code to make the changes more visible, to make sure I'd truly notice them if the would be picked up. But nothing.

I'm really grateful if someone can help.

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i figured it out myself - The problem is that i can have different folders with different names in my templates/my_template/html/mod_k2_content folder, but each folder needs to contain a default.php. I renamed the team.php in my templates/my_template/html/mod_k2_content/Team folder to default.php and now the changes are being picked up !

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure: did you disable the caching on the website as well as the caching on your browser?

Comment: I always do a hard refresh via Ctrl and F5 on my Firefox on windows